# Interpreting results from Sobol sensitivity analysis in R

Tags: r, sensitivity-analysis

I'm trying to use the sobol2007 model in the R sensitivity package. I'm doing runs on a model with 26 parameters, and using 2 sets of 500 monte-carlo samples to seed the analysis, and nboot=500. This results in 14k runs

When I generate the sensitivity results, I'm expecting numbers in 0..1, but I get both
* negative numbers
* very high numbers (e.g. 10)

When I plot the model, I can see that the confidence intervals are gigantic:
[image: Sobol sensitivity model output]

It feels like 14k runs should be reasonable to estimate this number of parameters, but maybe I'm being overly optimistic.

Can anyone answer:

- am I totally unrealistic, and/or how many runs should I be using?
- can I read anything from these outputs, or are they essentially so noisy as to be worthless?
- how should I be selecting nboot - there's no guidance in the docs?

Comment: The sample size seems very small for Sobol... Something in the four of five digits might help.

Comment: For the bootstrap, I think you might get away with 100.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sobol sensitivity indices do not require zero mean function but estimation formulae are not robust at all.
To avoid this kind of problem, a new formula has just been coded in the version 1.6 of the sensitivity package: soboljansen()

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the sobol sensitivity model requires zero-mean data to function:

```
X1 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(8 * n), nrow = n))
X2 <- data.frame(matrix(runif(8 * n), nrow = n)) #Random samples
x <- sobol(model = NULL, X1 = X1, X2 = X2, order = 1, nboot = 100) #Create model, first order only
r <- as.matrix(x$X,ncol=8) %*% c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); #Response is proportional to factor number
tell( x, (r-mean(r))/sd(r) ); plot(x) #Standardised
```

[image: Standardised response]

```
tell( x, r-mean(r) ); plot(x) #Zero mean
```

[image: Zero mean]

```
tell( x, r ); plot(x) #Unprocessed
```

[image: Unprocessed]

```
tell( x, r*1000 ); plot(x) #Scaled
```

[image: Scaled]

```
tell( x, r+40 ); plot(x) #Offset
```

[image: Offset]

So altogether it looks like scaling doesn't make much difference, but a non-zero mean throws it off completely.